# resizing chrome theme image to fit screen size

Tags: google-chrome-extension, resize

is there a way to make the background image of chrome theme resize with the height of the window? If so, can I also make the image resize with the height until it hist a certain ratio, and then resize with the width of the window?

Comment: Seems like a double "no", but I'm not an expert on the question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to change the display in the chrome://newtab page. You could edit the `style` attribute of the `body` HTML tag to add `background-size:contain`.
Prior to Chrome v61.0.3161.0, you could use Tampermonkey to run a custom script to inject that CSS piece. However, since then, Chrome no longer lets extensions (incl. Tampermonkey) run scripts in the newtab page (https://codereview.chromium.org/2978953002/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Chromium source code doesn't have any stretching/sizing  modes as you can see: [theme_properties.h](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/themes/theme_properties.h&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=59&rcl=1445657257), [theme_properties.cc](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/themes/theme_properties.cc&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=106) and [theme_service.cc](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/themes/theme_service.cc&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=295)

I've tried specifying an SVG image with `width="100%" height="100%"` for the background but it wasn't rendered, looks like only raster images can be used (WEBP, JPG, PNG, etc).

Comment: If you use zoom on the "New Tab" page with the image, it looks like Chrome will retain the zoom for that page - so, you can just zoom until the image fits the screen (assuming you don't mind a slightly larger Google logo)

Answer (score 0):

I tried use jpeg format, it resized itself, without anything added to manifest.json